# Will swishing water in your mouth after meals widen teeth gaps?

Tags: dentistry, gargling-gargle, rinsing-mouth, teeth-alignment, diastema-teeth-gaps

I have a small gap between my middle two teeth, I recently started swishing water in my mouth since I find it very effective at removing food stuck in or in-between teeth.

Is this a bad thing to do? Will this widen the gap between my teeth?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **No.** Using water, mouth rince, floss, toothpics or other **means of removing debris between teeth should not cause dental movement**.

Long answer: To cause dental movement, a *continuous pression or pull* has to be applied for *many* hours per day, over the span of weeks/months/years to make teeth move. That is why head gears have to be worn at least 12h everyday, and why braces are kept on at all times. Other problems, such as a bad occlusion (the way your teeth close together can also cause movements.

Therefore, weak and inetermitant forces (such as cleaning between your teeth) will have little effect on your dentition.

Sources: http://www.gillettedental.com/blog/post/orthodontic-headgear-what-it-is-and-why-it-may-be-needed.html